# Syntax highlighting for code doesn't work

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

The syntax described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) doesn't work for me. I used `<!-- language: lang-xaml -->` and `<!-- language: lang-c# -->`. Nothing works.

Here's what I wrote as an answer to some question.

```
XAML
<!-- language: lang-xaml -->

    <RadioButton>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </RadioButton>

C#
<!-- language: lang-c# -->

    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
    rb.Content = new TextBlock()
    {
        Text = "Sample",
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
    };
```

And here's how it looks like (below). Everything is black. Why?

XAML

```
<RadioButton>
    <TextBlock Text="This is very long text that I want to wrap. Is it long enough?" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</RadioButton>
```

C#

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.Content = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "This is very long text that I want to wrap. Is it long enough?",
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a newline *before* the comment too, otherwise it is just part of the preceding paragraph.

```
XAML

<!-- language: lang-xaml -->

    <RadioButton>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </RadioButton>

C#

<!-- language: lang-c# -->

    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
    rb.Content = new TextBlock()
    {
        Text = "Sample",
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
    };
```